# Why OptionMenu not show icon menu in 4.0 but work in 2.x.x

Tags: android, android-menu, optionmenu

I try to create OptionMenu which application's target is 15 but minSDK is 8. I Have one Menu folder and `mymenu.xml` in it. I wanna use the default icon menu and wanna make it support since sdk 8. How should it do that? The problem when i test is, the option menu icon show only on sdkVersion 8 but, not show on sdkVersion 15

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/my_menu" android:title="Send Mail" android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_send"></item>
</menu>
```

and in Activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.mymenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.my_menu:
            //Do something
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting with `Honeycomb` you are recommended to use the `ActionBar` to show the menu options(add `android:showAsAction="ifRoom"`(or one of the other options) to your menu item). The default will not show an icon.

Comment: where to define android:showAsAction="ifRoom" in program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action overflow -- what you are thinking of as the options menu on API Level 11+ -- does not show icons.

Comment: sorry, my bad. I set theme.holo.NOActionbar so, i din't see it

Comment: Is there any way to still show icons in the old-style menu for devices API 11+?  I don't want to show them in the actionbar since my actionbar already has tabs (and will be cluttered).

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky: AFAIK, there is no way to show "the old-style menu", unless you implement it yourself from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

@ohh: android:showAsAction="ifRoom", you can add it to your menu.xml